# Preview an Image before Upload

Tags: javascript

I want to preview an image before uploading it to the server. I am using the script below. The same script works fine in standalone HTMl, but when I run the same script in my jsp my application images which have been resized are not displayed. Any Help would be aprreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// width to resize large images to
var maxWidth = 200;
// height to resize large images to
var maxHeight = 200;
// valid file types
var fileTypes = [ "bmp", "gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg" ];
// the id of the preview image tag
var previewImage = "previewField";
// what to display when the image is not valid
var defaultPic = "spacer.gif";

var globalPic;
var extOk=false;


function preview(what) {

    var source = what.value;
    var imageName = source;
    var ext = source.substring(source.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, source.length).toLowerCase();
    for ( var i = 0; i < fileTypes.length; i++) {
        if (fileTypes[i] == ext) {
            extOk = true;
        }
    }
    if (extOk == true) {
        globalPic = new Image();
        imageName = imageName.replace(new RegExp(/\\/g),"/");
        globalPic.src ="file:///" + imageName;
        alert(globalPic.src);
        extOk = false;
        applyChanges();
    } else {
        alert(imageName);
        globalPic.src = defaultPic;
        alert("THAT IS NOT A VALID IMAGE\nPlease load an image with an extention of one of the following:\n\n"
                + fileTypes.join(", ") + "\n and not " + ext);
    }
}

function applyChanges() {


    var field = document.getElementById(previewImage);
    var x = parseInt(globalPic.width);
    var y = parseInt(globalPic.height);
    if (x > maxWidth) {
        y *= maxWidth / x;
        x = maxWidth;
    }
    if (y > maxHeight) {
        x *= maxHeight / y;
        y = maxHeight;
    }
    field.style.display = (x < 1 || y < 1) ? "none" : "";
    field.src = globalPic.src;
field.width = x;
    field.height = y;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this with the file api:

Add this to your preview function at the correct place:

```
var reader = new FileReader();  
reader.onload = (function(globalPic) { return function(e) { globalPic.src = e.target.result; }; })(globalPic);  
reader.readAsDataURL(what.files[0]);
```

Comment: Thnx for reply. But IE does not seem to support FileReader API.
Could you please send Code snippet as how to implement it.
The problem seems to be if Images have been resized works fine otherwise.

Comment: Yes the File API is not supported in IE. I've send the code snippet in my answer before already. What kind of image resize problem so you have?

Comment: Thnx for reply...Images(simple .JSP's) which I have resized using MSPaint or MSOffice Manager are not displayed using Javascript as posted above while rest images are displayed fine using same code...(Could you provide solution/Code snippet for IE Browser).Also when i use same Javascript Code in Stand Alone HTML it works fine.Problem is when i use same in my Application(IDE Eclipse)

Comment: `.JSP` files are not images so they can't be displayed using JavaScript. IE does not support the File API so it's not possible... even IE9 and 10 don't support it. The only thing you can do in IE is uploading the image and show it afterwards.